# Append string between each cell value in a series

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, worksheet-function, vba

Let's say I have a series of cells like so:

```
    A
1  Foo
2  Bar
3  Hello
4  World
5  Random Text
```

What I'd like to do is have the result of my formula populate another cell with:

```
Foo, Bar, Hello, World, Random Text
```

Now, I know how to concatenate two cells with:

```
=A1&", "&A2
```

but how can I do the same thing with the entire series?

Comment: I think you can't really do this with a formula, although I might be mistaken. This is a pretty simple implementation in a `For/Next` loop in VBA.

Comment: I cant find a way to do this with the built in formulas, you can make a custom formula to do this with David's suggestion

Comment: As `CONCATENATE` can't handle splicing together an array you are left with an ugly formula or a VBA solution

Comment: See my answer (now undeleted) from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406943/concatenate-many-cells-in-excel-with-formula#comment25276533_17406943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function you might be able to use. Simply put this in your workbook code module, then you can enter it in cells like:

`=JoinRange(A1:A6)` or `=JoinRange(A2:D15)`, etc.

```
Public Function JoinRange(ByVal rng As Range) As String
    Dim dlmt As String: dlmt = ","
    Dim multiRow As Boolean: multiRow = rng.Rows.Count > 1
    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    Select Case rng.Columns.Count
        Case 1
            If multiRow Then
                JoinRange = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng), dlmt)
            Else:
                'a single cell
                JoinRange = rng
            End If
        Case Is > 1
            If multiRow Then
                'a 2d range of cells:
                For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
                    For c = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
                        JoinRange = JoinRange & rng(r, c) & dlmt
                    Next
                Next
                JoinRange = Left(JoinRange, Len(JoinRange) - 1)

            Else:
                JoinRange = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose( _
                                Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng)), dlmt)
            End If
        Case Else

     End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a comma and a space in cell B1, then use this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,A2,B1,A3,B1,A4, B1, A5)
```

There are several answers to the following question that you can try as well, including VBA options and a formula:

[Need to concatenate varying number of cells...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1429245/138938)

Comment: I think he doesnt want to have to hard code each cell in the formula

Comment: You're probably right. I'll delete my answer if he doesn't find it helpful.

Comment: Check the answer I linked to. There are both VBA and formula options that you can probably use.

Answer (score 1):

With `=A1` in B1 then `=B1&", "&A2` in B2 and copied down would seem to work.